# Catching events from nested user control

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have some user controls. The hierarchy is as follows:

A contains B
B contains C

Inside my C control I have a button. When I click on it want my event

```
public event EventHandler Print;
```

to by raised and then I want control A to catch this event. How can I do this?

EDIT 1:
I want to raise my event on User Control C's ViewModel

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer but have you tried an event handler on B which would then pass this down to C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 topics that can help you fulfill your need:

[Commanding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx)
and
[Routed Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)

Both mechanisms are built specifically for wpf's hierarchical structure.

Read up on both, they will help your wpf experience immeasurably.

EDIT: Something more helpful. Put Button.Click="" on the control where you want to catch the event. You can use the button's Tag property to store identifying information so your event handler knows that the correct button was clicked.

```
<Grid Button.Click="Button_ClickHandler">
    <Button Tag="PrintButton/>
</Grid>
```

In your code behind for the user control you will require the handler named Button_ClickHandler.

The above method uses Router Events. I really recommend using Commands however.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think you want to look at [bubbling events](http://odetocode.com/Articles/94.aspx).</strike>

Update: I didn't see the wpf tag, you should be looking at [routed events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx)

Comment: This is a solution for ASP.net, not wpf.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the event like so:

```
class B
{
    private A a;

    public event EventHandler Print
    {
        add { a.Print += value; }
        remove { a.Print -= value; }
    }
}
```